Splitting Field of $x^4 - 10$ in $\mathbb{F}_7$
I am currently studying field theory and came across a problem that I need some help with. Specifically, I am interested in finding the splitting field of the polynomial $x^4 - 10$ over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_7$.
Given that $10 \equiv 3 \pmod{7}$, the polynomial can be rewritten as $x^4 - 3$. I would like to understand the following:

How to determine the roots of $x^4 - 3$ in $\mathbb{F}_7$.
What the splitting field of $x^4 - 3$ in $\mathbb{F}_7$ is and how to construct it.
The degree of the splitting field extension over $\mathbb{F}_7$.

I have currently gone by showing that $f(x) = (x^2 - \alpha)(x^2 + \alpha)$, where $\alpha$ is the root of $x^2 - 10$ in $\mathbb{F}_7(\alpha)$.
I'm not sure how to go forward.
Thank you!

It may be helpful to note that $X^4+4$ is reducible. As for determining the roots, there are only finitely many values to check.

not having root doesn't imply irreducibility, does it?
$x^4+4$ msy be product of two irreducible polynomials of degree 2.

As I said, it is indeed reducible. All of your questions follow directly from the observation that $X^4+4$ is a reducible quartic with no roots in $\mathbb{F}_7$.

Actually, you need one more fact: no roots are repeated.

$$\begin{align}x^4-3 &= x^4+4 \\ &=(x^4+4x^2+4)-4x^2 \\ &= (x^2+2)^2-4x^2 \\ &=(x^2-2x+2)(x^2+2x+2)\end{align}$$
Note that $x^2\pm 2 x + 2 = (x\pm 1)^2+1$ has no root in $\mathbb F_7$, as $\mathbb F_7$ doesn't contain any square-root of $-1$ (because $7\text{ mod } 4 = 3$). Therefore this cannot be further factored.
Both the splitting fields of $x^2-2x+2$ and $x^2+2x+2$ are $\mathbb F_{7^2}$, hence it must be the splitting field of $x^4-3$ as a whole.
